# DROOLS pattern matching nested lists with complex objects

Tags: drools

I'm struggling with a pattern-matching routine in DROOLs that traverses lists of complex nested objects.

I have a POJO structure something like this:

```
class MyFact {
    private List<A> listOfA;
    public List<A> getListOfA() { return listOfA; }
}

class A {
    private List<B> listOfB;
    private String stringField;
    public List<B> getListOfB() { return listOfB; }
    public String getStringField() { return stringField; }
}

class B {
    private String otherStringField;
    public String getOtherStringField() { return otherStringField; }
}
```

I am trying to find the correct syntax to collect all objects of type 'A' that match a set of criteria that also includes matching fields in objects contained within 'A's `listOfB`.

I think the rule needs to look something like this, but the pattern I have won't compile while it is inside the `collect( ... )`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
rule "Tricky Syntax"
when
    $myFact: MyFact()
    $filteredListOfA: ArrayList( size > 0 ) from collect ( 
        A( stringField == "something", $listOfB: listOfB ) from $myFact.listOfA
        B( otherStringField == "somethingElse" ) from $listOfB
    ) 
then
   // Do something neat with $filteredListOfA
end
```

I know it could be written in such a way where each element is matched iteratively but I only want to fire the action once and have a single List of A if there are any matches.
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible usind "collect" because multiple patterns aren't possible inside the collect CE. (Do you mean to collect A's or B's or both?) You can easily change this to accumulate which gives you full control over what is accumulated:

```
$myFact: MyFact()
$filteredListOfA: List( size > 0 ) from accumulate ( 
    $a: A( stringField == "something", $listOfB: listOfB ) from $myFact.listOfA
    and
    B( otherStringField == "somethingElse" ) from $listOfB;
    collectList( $a )
)
```

**Later**

If list elements should occur only once when elements in listOfA are selected more than once, simply use a `Set` and `collectSet`.

Comment: This is very useful and gets me further but isn't 100% correct. 
Need to remove the ; after "somethingElse" and change the ArrayList import to List (to avoid Class cast exception - UnmodifyableRandomAccessList to ArrayList).

Once fixed, the code returns a filteredListOfA that contains duplicates of A if we have multiple object B in $listOfB that match.

Now I understand the accumulate CE better, I think I can work around this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added Set as an alternative to eliminate duplicates

Comment: @laune please have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067399/drools-6-1-0-defaultfacthandle-notserializable-exception

Answer (score 1):

Some slight changes to fix syntax and remove duplicates of A using collectSet() instead of collectList()

```
import java.util.Set;
rule "Tricky Syntax"
when
    $myFact: MyFact()
    $filteredListOfA: Set( size > 0 ) from accumulate ( 
        $a: A( stringField == "something", $listOfB: listOfB ) from $myFact.listOfA
        and
        B( otherStringField == "somethingElse" ) from $listOfB;
        collectSet( $a )
    )
then
    // Do something with the $filteredListOfA Set
end
```

Thanks to [laune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2107876/laune) for pointing a DROOLs noob in the right direction!

Also, it is worth noting that using collectSet() and collectList() the match order will not necessarily be retained (due to DROOLs LIFO behavior). Here is an alternative solution that retains the match order for the action (if that is important).

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
rule "Tricky Syntax"
when
    $myFact: MyFact()
    $filteredListOfA: Set( size > 0 ) from accumulate ( 
        $a: A( stringField == "something", $listOfB: listOfB ) from $myFact.listOfA
        and
        B( otherStringField == "somethingElse" ) from $listOfB,
        init( Set set = new LinkedHashSet(); ),
        action( set.add( $a ); ),
        result( set )
    )
then
    // Do something with the $filteredListOfA Set
end
```