# Drools 6.1.0 DefaultFactHandle NotSerializable exception

Tags: weblogic, drools, stateful

We are running drools 6.1.0 on Weblogic 12.1.2 as a stateless EJB 3.0 Bean. The bean returns the following exception when there is more load on the server during the initialization process when it is creating new instances in the pool.

```
EJB Exception: : java.lang.RuntimeException:         java.io.NotSerializableException: org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle
    at org.drools.core.util.ClassUtils.deepClone(ClassUtils.java:514)
    at     org.drools.core.definitions.impl.KnowledgePackageImpl.deepCloneIfAlreadyInUse(Kn    owledgePackageImpl.java:770)
    at     org.drools.core.definitions.impl.KnowledgePackageImpl.deepCloneIfAlreadyInUse(KnowledgePackageImpl.java:66)
at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.addPackages(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:722)
at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.addKnowledgePackages(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:266)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.createKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:412)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:346)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:498)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:443)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:425)
```

The code we have to initialize a new stateful session is as below:

```
protected KieSession kieSession= null;
protected ReleaseId releaseId = null; //fetched by logic to identify the release id>
if(kieSession != null){
    kieSession.dispose();
    kieSession = null;
}
KieServices kServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer container = kServices.newKieContainer(this.releaseId);
kieSession = container.newKieSession();
```

This is happening in the constructor of the Stateless Bean.

Could you help us with any suggestions on resolving this issue?

Comment: @laune, please have a look on this question. Thanks

Comment: This could be a bug - there isn't anything you could to at this stage and level to cause such an error. Seeing you are at 6.1.0, trying with 6.3.0 is something you should do before reporting a bug.

Comment: @laune hi, I am getting error while running version drools 6.3.0 final. : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequest.setTransferListener(Lorg/eclipse/aether/transfer/TransferListener;)Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest;

Comment: Both could be due to a version mixup between what you see at compile time or at runtime, or similar.

Comment: We have updated the drools version to 6.3.0 final and we are still facing this issue.

Comment: @laune We are still facing the same issue after updating the drools version 6.3.0 final. I have posted on drools goggle group. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/9dalKVRX3s0